# Inconsistent trying to put water stamp

Tags: php, image, php-gd

I'm trying to setup a procedure for making a water stamp.

The code:

// Add watermark

```
      // Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
      $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('./uploads/waterstamp.png');

      // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
      $marge_right = 10;
      $marge_bottom = 10;
      $sx = imagesx($stamp);
      $sy = imagesy($stamp);

      // Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
      // width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
      imagecopy($rotate, $stamp, imagesx($rotate) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($rotate) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

      // Output and free memory
      imagejpeg($rotate, $filename);
      imagedestroy($source);
      imagedestroy($rotate);
```

It works, but it is inconsistent. The water stamp is down right. In one of the to photos it looks correct but in one it is a white bounding box. I have to little reputation to attach the screen shot showing the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: I might be one step closer to a solution. Before the water stamp part a image is uploaded and scaled down. It seems like the problem only occur when the uploaded photo is larger than 1 MB. Can it be some sort of memory problem at the server?